# Monitor control to set up screen brightness using Windows Color Calibration

Tags: color, display-calibration, monitors

This sounds to be a simple question but I've been strugling around for the last 2 hours and nothing yet...

I need urgently to calibrate the color of my notebook (Samsung Odyssey). The procedure I'm following is the one you can see at this link:

[How to Calibrate Your Monitor in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/calibrate-monitor-windows-10)

I'm at the step 5 of the procedure, specifically at the "**Adjust the brightness and contrast**" topic.

My problem is that at this part (Adjust the brightness and contrast) Windows says to me: "Using the **controls in your display**, set the brightness higher or lower until you can distinguish the shirt from the suit with the X barely visible"

So the main question is: where is the "controls in your display"??

I heard at one video that such "controls" can vary each manufactor so I literally I've pressed all key (with Ctrl and Fn) of the keyboard but without succss! I've also downloaded the notebook manual but found nothing there.

Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: According to page 38 of the manual "The LCD screen is automatically set to the brightest level when the AC adapter is connected. The LCD screen automatically becomes dimmer when the AC adapter is disconnected." maybe that's causing your problems  http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201805/20180510145715161/Win10_Manual_ENG.pdf

Answer (score 1):

These controls are common on stand-alone monitors. Even low-end models let you control contrast and brightness, and more expensive ones will have more options.

But controls beyond brightness are rare — maybe even nonexistent — on laptop screens. You can't find the controls because they are not there.

Brightness is also a unique challenge with laptops due to portability — with my desktop system monitor, I'm pretty happy finding a brightness suited to the room and location. But with my laptop, I can't do that: sometimes I'm in very bright sunlight, and sometimes I'm literally in the dark. There is no one best setting.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop LCD brightness and contrast are controlled via software. One of the system tray icons may have the control. Look for a monitor icon. You can also try these instructions from Microsoft: [Change screen brightness in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026946/windows-10-change-screen-brightness).

There are usually keys on the keyboard to control brightness, but not contrast. I don't know specifically which keys they're on because there are multiple laptops named "Odyssey" that have different keyboards. **Look for icons that look like the sun on the function or arrow keys.**

Laptops screens are usually at their best when brightness is turned all the way up. (Whereas phones are usually at their best somewhere close to middle.) You can control "gamma" to some extent by varying your vertical viewing angle.